# Как завершить работу скрипта, не завершая запущенную из него программу?

Tags: python, subprocess

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы скрипт завершал свою работу после того как выполнит функцию.
На данный момент скрипт будет ожидать завершения программы сервера, а мне нужно, чтобы он просто запустил и завершился, а сервер продолжал работать.

```
import psutil
import subprocess


exe_path_serv = r'C:\servers_asa\island\ShooterGame\Binaries\Win64\ArkAscendedServer.exe'
exe_path_steamCMD = r'C:\asmdata\SteamCMD\steamcmd.exe'
additional_args_serv = r'TheIsland_WP?listen?'
additional_args_CMD = '+force_install_dir C:\servers_asa\island\ +login anonymous +app_update 2430930'

def is_process_running(exe_path):
    for process in psutil.process_iter(['exe']):
        if process.info['exe'] == exe_path:
            return True
    return False

def start_program(exe_path, additional_args):
    try:
        command = f'"{exe_path}" {additional_args}'
        subprocess.run(command, shell=True, close_fds=True)
        print(f'Программа по пути {exe_path} успешно запущена с параметрами: {additional_args}')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Ошибка при запуске программы: {e}')

def run_server(path_srv, arg_srv, update=False):

    if is_process_running(path_srv):
        print(f'Сервер уже запущен')
        return
    
    if update:
        start_program(exe_path_steamCMD, additional_args_CMD)

    start_program(path_srv, arg_srv)

run_server(exe_path_serv, additional_args_serv, update=False)
```

Пробовал так и тоже не работает:

```
def start_program(exe_path, additional_args):
    try:
        command = f'"{exe_path}" {additional_args}'
        subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, close_fds=True)
        print(f'Программа по пути {exe_path} успешно запущена с параметрами: {additional_args}')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Ошибка при запуске программы: {e}')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1196074/4827341

Comment: "Как завершить работу скрипа" — это кто такой, "скрип"?